# How to join multiple select statements in SQL

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, join, subquery

I would like to know how a query of this form could be improved on in terms of 1) Style and 2) Performance. In case it matters, I'm using Oracle as my database. Also, the purpose of this query is to select all records from the first select statement that do not have a corresponding record in the set of records to the right of the LEFT JOIN. The records from ColumnA are not necessarily unique in any of the tables.

```
select ColumnA
from
    (Select ColumnA
    from Table1)
left join
    ((select ColumnA, ColumnB
    from Table2)
    union
    (select ColumnA, ColumnB
    from Table3))
using (ColumnA)
where ColumnB is null
group by ColumnA;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Due to left joins and null tests: Are any of the columns defined as NOT NULL?

Comment: Yes, neither column is NULL in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could rewrite this query to the following (see this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4550/13)**):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM    (SELECT  ColumnA
         FROM    Table1)

MINUS

(SELECT  ColumnA
FROM    Table2
UNION
SELECT  ColumnA
FROM    Table3);
```

As for style, I'd recommend using the explicit join condition syntax `LEFT JOIN ... ON table1.somecolumn = table2.someothercolumn` instead of the `USING` condition, for readability and clarity. But this might well be personal preference :-)

Comment: I like this form because it is exactly the logic I'm trying to implement. Are there any reasons why this form may not be prefered due to style? How about performance?

Comment: You might want to use EXPLAIN PLAN to compare execution plans for queries. Here's a recent SO post on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576158/understanding-explain-plan-in-oracle

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the need for the `UNION`:

```
select T1.ColumnA
from Table1 T1
    left join Table2 T2 ON T1.ColumnA = T2.ColumnA
    left join Table3 T3 ON T1.ColumnA = T3.ColumnA
where T2.ColumnA IS NULL 
    or T3.ColumnA IS NULL
group by T1.ColumnA;
```

Another option would be to use `NOT IN`:

```
select distinct ColumnA
from Table1 
where ColumnA not in (select ColumnA from Table2) 
    and ColumnA not in (select ColumnA from Table3);
```

Both of these should return any ColumnA records in Table1 that aren't in Table2 or Table3.

Comment: +1 . . . I think the second option is the clearer option, although it should be `select distinct ColumnA`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- completely correct, forgot about the group by!

Comment: I asked this below, but it applies here to this answer as well. As far as style is concerned, is there a preference between using joins or subqueries?

Comment: You should use `AND` instead of `OR` in where clause of your first query

Answer (score 2):

Here are three alternatives.

```
select distinct ColumnA
  from Table1      a
  left join Table2 b using(ColumnA)
  left join Table3 c using(ColumnA)
 where b.ColumnB is null
   and c.ColumnB is null;
```

.

```
select distinct ColumnA
  from Table1 a
 where ColumnA not in(select ColumnA from Table2)
   and ColumnA not in(select ColumnA from Table3);
```

.

```
select distinct ColumnA
  from Table1 a
 where ColumnA not in(select ColumnA from Table2 union
                      select ColumnA from Table3);
```

Comment: As far as style is concerned, is there a preference between using joins or subqueries?

Comment: You should use `AND` instead of `OR` in where clause of your first query